# Retrieving Tags from web pages

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, bho, ihtmldocument2

I am working on a (Browser Helper Object) plugin for Internet Explorer using C++. I intend to use IHTMLDocument2 interface to fetch all tags from a Web page, identify phone numbers and add a hyperlink next to it.

Could someone provide me with a basic sample code for retrieving all tags (Using IHTMLDocument2)from the web page or guide me to some webpage ?

**UPDATE**
I have an alternative approach of adding a javascript to the page using the bho. the javascript could be used to add hyperlinks besides the phone numbers. Is this a better approach ?

Thanks